# How to create a temporary file under iis

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to create a temporary zip file under iis, so i can access it by an http request. in addition i want to delete this file after download it.
N.B. : i'm using asp.net 3.5 framework.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to create the file in a `MemoryStream` and serve it in a handler (`ashx`) assuming you're using web forms. The process is similar even when using MVC, though.

Comment: and what if client is submitting .xls file? As .xls can't be read by OLEDB from memory stream.

Comment: OP is talking about generating a file on the server in order to send it to the client. You seem to be talking about a file that a client sent to the server probably using an HTML form. Not the same problem...